# Mostrar itemLabel ao invés de um ivemValue em DataTable - JSF, Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ejb, cdi

Bom, estou trabalhando em um projeto e ao salvar um cadastro usando o selectOneMenu do primefaces, está sendo exibido um Id ao invés do nome do campo que foi selecionado, preciso saber como exibir somente o nome do campo.

Aqui o meu xhtml:

```
<p:outputLabel for="tipoTratamentoCB" value="Tipo de tratamento:" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoTratamentoCB"
                    value="#{guiaEncaminhamentoBean.guiaEncaminhamento.tipoTratamentoCB}"
                    style="width:185px">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hospitalização Diurna - HD" itemValue="0" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Hospitalização Noturna - HN" itemValue="1" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Minha variável tipoTratamentoCB é declarada a assim na minha classe:

```
private String tipoTratamentoCB;
```

O problema é que eu exibo no meu xhtml o valor que é salvo em ivemValue no selectItem, preciso saber como exibir o valor do itemLabel, alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi corretamente, você quer guardar o valor do itemLabel em tipoTratamentoCB. Se for isso, tente alterar o seguinte:

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Hospitalização Diurna - HD" itemValue="Hospitalização Diurna - HD" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Hospitalização Noturna - HN" itemValue="Hospitalização Diurna - HD" />
```